# use onChange function in javascript multi time

Tags: javascript, onchange

I want to check value of input with onchange function,for example when count is greater than programmable count show Error message and if count is less than programmable hide Error message with this code:

```
 <input type="hidden" value="{{$record->programmable()}}" id="programmable">
 <input min="0" max="{{$record->programmable()}}" type="number" name="count" 
 onchange="checkCount(this.value)">

  <script>
    function checkCount(value) {
        var programmable = $('#programmable').val();
        if (value > programmable) {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("insertData").disabled = true;
        }
        else if (value < programmable) {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("insertData").disabled = false;
        }
    }
  </script>
```

when I enter count greater than programmable Error Message shown But when I Enter less than programmable Error message don't be hide,How I can fixed it?

Comment: Please create a snippet `[<>]` so we have a [mcve] - also tag the framework used

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the problem but,
you missed a quotation mark (") after type="number **"**

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your number field (`type="number`). I don't know what error did you get but I noticed that you mixed up jQuery with this JS. Also in your HTML I found missing the ID `errorMessage` and `insertData`. Whatsoever, I have added a demo here for you and hope it will help you to correct your code.

```js
function checkCount(value) {
    var programmable = document.getElementById('programmable').value;
    if (value > programmable) {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("insertData").disabled = true;
    }
    else if (value < programmable) {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("insertData").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="2" id="programmable">
<input min="0" max="5" type="number" name="count" onchange="checkCount(this.value)" placeholder="Please enter number">
<input type="button" id="insertData" value="Insert">

<div id="errorMessage" style="display: none">Error</div>
```

Comment: I Enter 10 in your Answer and don't get Error,when I should be arranged

Comment: If you enter it manually then you have add the `onkeyup` event. Error message will be shown if you change the value by clicking arrow symbol right of the text field. Since the current event is `onchange`.